# VBA-style range selection in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

In a spreadsheet formula, (namely `SumIfs`) I would like to be able to select a column range using its delimiters instead of a A1:A3456 style, like I would do in VBA `[Range("A1:A3456")~Range(Cells(1,1),Cells(3456,1))]`.

If this is not possible, is there any workaround to use the result of a 'Match' function to get the column number where I want to apply certain criteria?

My function would look like

```
=Sumifs(A2:A10;*{range(cells(1,match(Z5;A1:T1)), cell(10,match(Z5;A1:T1))}*,"="&1)
```

...if only I could add vba formulas inside the spreadsheet.

Comment: Check this : https://support.office.com/en-us/article/OFFSET-function-c8de19ae-dd79-4b9b-a14e-b4d906d11b66

Comment: You can use RC format as the first thing coming to mind.  R1C1 is A1, and you can offset with this as well, e.g. in Cell B2 you write "=RC[-1]" it gives the reference to the cell in the same row and column minus 1, or A1.

Comment: Explore the options the INDEX function gives you, in conjunction with MATCH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a combination of `Address` and `Indirect`, like this:

```
=SUM(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(1,1) & ":" & ADDRESS(3456,1)))
```

which is equivalent to `=SUM(A1:A3456)`

`ADRESS` transforms from style `Cells(i,j)` to style `A1`.

`INDIRECT` serves to interpret the resulting string as a range address.

`SUM` here is an example of usage.

Well It's a bit ugly, but if you want to do that *occasionally* and don't want to switch completely to `RC-style`, it's probably the easiest way.

Answer (score 0):

Use Offset, which is much richer as a worksheet function than it is in VBA.

> Syntax
>
> OFFSET(reference, rows, cols, [height], [width])
>
> The OFFSET function syntax has the following arguments:
>
> Reference    Required. The reference from which you want to base the
>   offset. Reference must refer to a cell or range of adjacent cells;
>   otherwise, OFFSET returns the #VALUE! error value.
>
> Rows    Required. The number of rows, up or down, that you want the
>   upper-left cell to refer to. Using 5 as the rows argument specifies
>   that the upper-left cell in the reference is five rows below
>   reference. Rows can be positive (which means below the starting
>   reference) or negative (which means above the starting reference).
>
> Cols    Required. The number of columns, to the left or right, that
>   you want the upper-left cell of the result to refer to. Using 5 as the
>   cols argument specifies that the upper-left cell in the reference is
>   five columns to the right of reference. Cols can be positive (which
>   means to the right of the starting reference) or negative (which means
>   to the left of the starting reference).
>
> Height    Optional. The height, in number of rows, that you want the
>   returned reference to be. Height must be a positive number.
>
> Width    Optional. The width, in number of columns, that you want the
>   returned reference to be. Width must be a positive number.

from https://support.office.com/en-us/article/OFFSET-function-c8de19ae-dd79-4b9b-a14e-b4d906d11b66